# Metamask address not detected on remix-ide

Tags: remix, metamask

My Metamask address wont show up on remix-ide either run on localhost and remix.ethereum.org

[image: remix shows like this]

I also have tried it on brave and chrome, none of them show the address.
please help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you should unlock your metamask, then go for the remix and select "injected web3". If the metamask is locked or doesn't have any imported account,the following account section in the remix will be empty.Hope its helps. 
**Important : please check that in metamask setting the privacy mode is "turned off" , it may also cause problem for external website to access metamask accounts.**

Comment: thanks mate. My privacy mode is turned on after turn it off, the problem solved.

Comment: Thanks. Turning off the privacy mode actually does the trick. :)